# How to use S3 for Production on Heroku and local static css for development?

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, gruntjs

I have just installed Grunt in my Django app.  In my `blogengine` app I have the folder: `assets/css/global.scss`.  Grunt minifies this .scss file to `static/css/global.css`.

I am still developing the app locally.  I have been running grunt sass and watch to minify the scss file to css as I'm working on it.

However, I've set the static url, etc to be my Amazon S3 bucket.  This means when I run `collectstatic`, I have to wait ages for it to upload to S3 so I can see my changes.

I am wanting to eventually deploy this to Heroku, but in the meantime, how do I set my static content to work locally and setup production settings to use S3?

This is in settings.py:

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'ingledow'

STATIC_URL = 'http://ingledow.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could mess with the DEBUG settings. In local development, set DEBUG to True, and Django will handle serving all the static files. Once you push to production, set DEBUG to False and the S3 settings will kick in. You could have different settings files or you could set an environment variable both locally and on Heroku and call it in your settings (i.e.: `DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG'].

Answer (score 0):

In your bashrc, set a environment flag:

```
alias DJANGO_ENV=local
```

(Alternatively, just do this in your local shell: export DJANGO_ENV=local)

Then in settings.py:

```
import os
if os.environ.get( 'DJANGO_ENV', '' ) == 'local':
  # SETUP LOCAL SETTINGS
else:
  STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'

  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
  AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'ingledow'

  STATIC_URL = 'http://ingledow.s3.amazonaws.com/'
```

Turn off the local settings when doing pushstatic (eg. "unset DJANGO_ENV"). On production (ie. Heroku), you won't have the DJANGO_ENV system variable, so it will default to AWS files.